# Terminal shows strange characters where is computer name

Tags: bash, ssh

I have ssh'ed to other computer and terminal showing strange character where is computer name and time. Bash version 4.3.48(1)-release.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

What should I do to fix that issue?

Comment: Using [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline)?

Comment: Checked, powerline isn't installed.

Comment: what is value of PS1
do `echo $PS1`

Comment: @sourav `$ echo $PS1
\n\033[01;37m\][\A]\033[0m\]\007\[\033[1;30m\](\033[0;36m\]\u\033[01;36m\]@\033[0;36m\]\H\[\033[1;30m\]) \[\033[1;36m\w\033[0m\]\n$` 
Could be the problems related with locale? Because, I've got warning:  Setting locale failed.

Comment: which os you're using,

Comment: run this command `uname -a`

Comment: I'm sure this is your PS1 value problem man nothing else

Comment: @sourav `Linux RUB-RUMC-1 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: set the PS1 value with this `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

Comment: Tried to made export in termiinal, then in .bashrc, reconnected, still the same.
`$ echo $PS1
\n\033[01;37m\][\A]\033[0m\]\007\[\033[1;30m\](\033[0;36m\]\u\033[01;36m\]@\033[0;36m\]\H\[\033[1;30m\]) \[\033[1;36m\w\033[0m\]\n$`

Comment: What client do you use for ssh?

Comment: @pa4080 OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: in .bashrc what is your PS1 values, it should be like this
`if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
`

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas if your PS1 value is not like this then change this as a root user

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is VMware cloud instance running with Linux. Maybe it has a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that something changes you `PS1` value, you may re-export it to get it back.

You can use `export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'` for a simple test.

Or you can use `export PS1='\033[01;37m[\A]\033[0m\[\033[0;36m\]\u\033[01;36m@\H\[\033[1;36m\w\033[0m\]\n$'` for your previous `PS style`.

Comment: Same thing. I guess this is VMware fault some how because when I am connect through VMware cloud web page console, it doesn't happen.